# Using foreach loop with List<>

Tags: c#

I have an array like this

```
public List<Application> all_roads = new List<Application>();
```

And an object with fields:

```
public string point_of_distination;
public uint length_of_route;
public double price;
public string our_drv_name;
public string our_drv_surname;
public string our_bus_model;
public double gen_ticket_price;
public short cur_year;
public byte cur_day;
public byte cur_month;
public double tour_consumption;
```

I would like to count general sum of `tour_consumption` from all objects.
How should I write `foreach` loop for this ?
Please, help me.

Comment: `foreach (Application a in all_roads)`

Comment: Thank you, Uriel Eli. You right!

Comment: For future reference, please see [this article](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) on how to ask for help with homework.

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to calculate `tour_consumption` you can try this:

```
var sum = all_roads.Sum(x => x.tour_consumption);
```

You don't need to select `tour_consumption` explicitly. You can just pass lambda expression directly to `Sum()` function.

Please read how LINQ `Sum()` method works in following [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534734(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also please make sure that you included `System.Linq` namespace if you want to consume `Sum()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Be a lot easier just using Linq:

```
var sum = all_roads.Sum(x => x.tour_consumption);
```

If you really wanted to use a for loop:

```
double sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < all_roads.Count; i++)
{
   sum += all_roads[i].tour_consumption;
}
```

or foreach loop

```
double sum = 0;
foreach (var app in all_roads)
{
   sum += app.tour_consumption;
}
```

Comment: You could also do Sum(x -> x.tour_consumption) without the explicit call to Select.

Comment: I think that your second case with `i<=all_roads.Count` will produce `index out of range` exception. Can you please verify that and correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Yeah good call... updated with improvements and correction within for loop :) thanks

Comment: @KevinSmith No problem, you should at least upvote my comment. I saved you from downvote ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
double sum = 0;
foreach (var item in all_roads)
{
   sum += tour_consumption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone else said:

```
double sum = 0.0;
foreach (var app in all_roads)
    sum += app.tour_consumption;
```

You can also check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx for more info on `foreach` loops or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx for more info on Lambda Expressions